# using map to convert a string to date of a nested value in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data object that looks like this:

```
[{
  "key": "K1204",
  "values": [{
    "key": "Both",
    "values": [{
      "key": "2015-01",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "2015-02",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "2015-03",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }]
  }, {
    "key": "Only 1",
    "values": [{
      "key": "2015-01",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "2015-02",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "2015-03",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "key": "test",
  "values": [{
    "key": "Both",
    "values": [{
      "key": "2015-01",
      "values": 1602.24390394729
    }, {
      "key": "2015-02",
      "values": 1602.24390394729
    }, {
      "key": "2015-03",
      "values": 1602.24390394729
    }]
  }, {
    "key": "Only 1",
    "values": [{
      "key": "2015-01",
      "values": 0
    }, {
      "key": "2015-02",
      "values": 0
    }, {
      "key": "2015-03",
      "values": 0
    }]
  }, {
    "key": "Only 2",
    "values": [{
      "key": "2015-01",
      "values": 104732.0298
    }, {
      "key": "2015-02",
      "values": 104732.0298
    }, {
      "key": "2015-03",
      "values": 104732.0298
    }]
  }]
}]
```

I'm trying to convert the date string in `key` to a date but I'm not able to get my code to work...

here is what I have so far:

```
get_scn_cst_data().then(function(costByScn) {
  var data2 = []
  for(i = 0; i < costByScn.length; i++) {
    var envs = costByScn[i]
    for(j = 0; j < envs.length; j++) {
      envs[j].["values"].map(function(data) {
        data["key"] = new Date(data["key"]).getTime();
        data2.push(data);
      });
    }
  }
  console.log("data2: ", JSON.stringify(costByScn));
  $scope.data_costByScn = costByScn;
});
```

I think I'm on the right track but the loops don't seem to be working correctly...

the only error I get to is this: `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=comparisonReportsController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined`

-----EDIT-----

tried it this way with no luck:

```
get_scn_cst_data().then(function(costByScn){

                var data2 = []

                for(i=0;i<costByScn.length;i++) {

                    var envs = costByScn[i]

                    for(j=0;j<envs.length;j++) {

                        data2.push(envs[j].["values"].map(function(data) {
                            data["key"] = new Date(data["key"]).getTime();
                            return data;
                        }));
                    }
                }

                console.log("data2: ", JSON.stringify(costByScn));

                $scope.data_costByScn =   costByScn;

})
```

Comment: `2015-01` is only a year and a month. A JavaScript date also represents a day and exact time plus timezone. How are you planning to deal with that?

Comment: yes, which is fine for my purposes, I just need to get it into a date format so I can plot it using nvd3...

Comment: just tried that and no luck....the only error I get is this too `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=comparisonReportsController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined`

Comment: I don't think you need the `map` or `data2` at all... you can just replace the date value with your new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
for(i = 0; i < costByScn.length; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j<costByScn[i].values.length; j++) {
    var envs = costByScn[i].values[j];
    costByScn[i].values[j].values = envs.values.map(function(env) {
    var obj = env;
    obj.key = new Date(obj.key).getTime();
    return obj;
  })
  }
}
console.log("data2: ", JSON.stringify(costByScn));
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice and functional way to do it:

```
var dates = [];

costByScn.forEach(function(scn) {
  scn.values.forEach(function(value) {
    value.values.forEach(function(value2) {
      dates.push(new Date(value2.key));
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle with an updated version of your first code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/q9e6mc6m/2/

A few things that will hopefully explain why your solution wasn't working:

```
var envs = costByScn[i]
```

should be

```
var envs = costByScn[i].values;
```

because you are trying to iterate over the `values` array. Otherwise `envs` is an object with `{ key: "..", values: {}}` which you can't use a `for` loop on. It's a bit confusing because the data structure has nested keys with the same name (values.values).

Also this line:

```
data2.push(envs[j].["values"].map(function(data) {
```

has an extra period `.` It should just be `envs[j]["values"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        let obj = JSON.parse('[{    "key": "K1204", "values": [{        "key": "Both",      "values": [{            "key": "2015-01",           "values": 27927.7349421797      }, {            "key": "2015-02",           "values": 27927.7349421797      }, {            "key": "2015-03",           "values": 27927.7349421797      }]  }, {        "key": "Only 1",        "values": [{            "key": "2015-01",           "values": 289819.9054       }, {            "key": "2015-02",           "values": 289819.9054       }, {            "key": "2015-03",           "values": 289819.9054       }]  }]}, {  "key": "test",  "values": [{        "key": "Both",      "values": [{            "key": "2015-01",           "values": 1602.24390394729      }, {            "key": "2015-02",           "values": 1602.24390394729      }, {            "key": "2015-03",           "values": 1602.24390394729      }]  }, {        "key": "Only 1",        "values": [{            "key": "2015-01",           "values": 0     }, {            "key": "2015-02",           "values": 0     }, {            "key": "2015-03",           "values": 0     }]  }, {        "key": "Only 2",        "values": [{            "key": "2015-01",           "values": 104732.0298       }, {            "key": "2015-02",           "values": 104732.0298       }, {            "key": "2015-03",           "values": 104732.0298       }]  }]}]');

        for (idx = 0; idx < obj.length; idx++){
            for (idxV = 0; idxV < obj[idx].values[0].values.length; idxV++){
                console.log(obj[idx].values[0].values[idxV].key);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Immutable, pure functions, easy to test and reason about:

```
const convertYearMonthStringToDateObject =
    (yearMonthString) => new Date(yearMonthString)

const transformItemProperty = (arr, property, transformFn) => arr.map(
    (item) => Object.assign({}, item, {[property]: transformFn(item[property])})
)

const mapKeys = (arr) =>
    transformItemProperty(arr, 'key', convertYearMonthStringToDateObject)
const mapValues = (arr) => transformItemProperty(arr, 'values', mapKeys)
const convertData = (arr) => transformItemProperty(arr, 'values', mapValues)
```